# Difference between libasan packes (libasan0, libasan2, libasan3, etc)

Tags: gcc, clang

There are many similar named packages for libasan (the address sanitizer for gcc and clang):

```
$ apt-cache search libasan | grep -v dbg | grep -v cross
libasan2 - AddressSanitizer -- a fast memory error detector
libasan3 - AddressSanitizer -- a fast memory error detector
libasan4 - AddressSanitizer -- a fast memory error detector
libasan0 - AddressSanitizer -- a fast memory error detector
```

(Output is from Ubuntu 17.10. Ubuntu 18.04 also has `libasan5`.)

- What is the difference between these packages?
- Which one should I install?

Comment: Have you tried to read the info of those packages?You can check using this  apt-cahe show packagename or apt-cache policy packagename

Comment: @bhordupur Thanks, as far as I understand, the difference is that each package corresponds to a different gcc version. libasan0 is for the oldest gcc, and each newer gcc receives a new libasan package. To answer my question, I assume you should install the package that matches the version of gcc that was used to compile the program.

Comment: Yes that's always the case and if package has the dependency on any of those then package should recommend/throw error that particular version of gcc for example. Well, you have answered your own question in the comment. And it's handy to check the improvement from libasan0 to libasan5. In general we  always let the system decide to install the suitable and compatible one unless we specify the particular version with the package itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is the difference between these packages?

The different packages are for different versions of gcc:

- libasan0: gcc-4.8
- libasan2: gcc-5
- libasan3: gcc-6
- libasan4: gcc-7
- libasan5: gcc-8

To find out that information, you can look at the packages details: `apt-cache show libsan0`

> Which one should I install?

The version that matches the gcc version that you used to compile the program.

Comment: You could mention that library can be identified via `$(gcc -print-file-name=libasan.so)`.